# Error while parsing string to date with dateutil.parser

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I am getting an error while trying to parse a string to date.

> ValueError: unknown string format

Here is my code

```
dateString = "02/11/2016"
 print dateString
 dt = parse(dateString)
 item.date = calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple())
 print dt
```

The funny part is, it is printing the correct date before throwing the error. Here is the complete log

> 02/11/2016 
>   2016-02-11 00:00:00 
>   art. 10, comma 1, lettera e  Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "institutional-docs.py", line 60, in
>   
>       dt = parse(dateString)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py",
>   line 697, in parse
>       return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/parser.py",
>   line 303, in parse
>       raise ValueError, "unknown string format" ValueError: unknown string format

Comment: Seems strange it works for me. Did you cut and paste the code from an example? The only thing that I can think of is that maybe there is some type of hidden character in the string.

Comment: @aquil.abdullah Is there a way for me to check that?

Comment: @aquil.abdullah the data that I am using is coming from a scrapped data. I am escaping the unicode characters. This is what I am doing to ignore them
`unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', dateString).encode('ascii','ignore')`

Comment: The easiest way to see if you have any hidden characters left in the string would be to log the results of ```print repr(dateString)```

Comment: @aquil.abdullah Its printing `'2 nov 2016' `. Can you please tell me how I can remove them? I just started with python

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with using [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)?

your question doesn't specify what your `parse` function does so can't say if that's reading the string in any weird way. Chances are you've copied and pasted bad quotation marks.

```
import time
time.strptime("02/11/2016", "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: The string that I have is in the format "2 nov 2016". Don't think time can handle that conversion :/

Comment: `"%d %b %Y"` read the time module. you'll be surprised at how many things it can handle

Comment: Will give it a try. Thanks a lot

Comment: the codes are all listed https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime and you can just define a date format that suits your needs.

Comment: The same strange thing is happening again. Its able to identify and convert the string. But in the end, it still throws error saying its not in a valid format.
here is the log

Comment: String: 2 nov 2016
log: time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=307, tm_isdst=-1)
Error: ValueError: time data 'art. 10, comma 1, lettera e ' does not match format '%d %b %Y'

Comment: I think its cause of some hidden characters in the string. I am using a scrapped data for the conversion. May be thats got something to do with it.

Comment: ` Error: ValueError: time data 'art. 10, comma 1, lettera e ' does not match format '%d %b %Y' ` is saying you are trying to convert the string: `'art. 10, comma 1, lettera e '` which does not seem like a date format to me. So something is wrong with you extracting time values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127282/discussion-between-kanishka-and-tom).

Comment: ValueError: unconverted data remains: